# LINQ - SELECT DISTINCT with NOT IN

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I'm have a SQL statement which I am trying to transform in a LINQ statement...

```
SELECT DISTINCT mc.*
     FROM ManufractorCategories mc 
WHERE mc.Active = 'true'
AND mc.Folder = 'false'
AND (mc.Id not in (SELECT Category_id FROM Manufractor_Category 
                        WHERE Manufractor_id = 3));
```

That's my last, not working LINQ statement

```
(IQueryable<object>)db.ManufractorCategories
                .Where(o => o.Active == active)
                .Where(o => o.Folder == folder)
                .Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Folder }).Except(db.Manufractor_Categories.Where(t => t.Manufractor_id == id).Select(t => new { t.Category_id })).Distinct();
```

I've tried the whole Sunday on that, but the Except statement won't work.

Thanks in advances for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Except` method requires two sets of the same type - this means that you would have to select objects of type `ManufractorCategory` in the nested query as well as in the outer query - then it would select all categories that are in the first one and not in the second one.

An easier alternative is to use the `Contains` method to check whether the current ID is in a list of IDs that you want to filter. The following should work:

```
var q = 
  db.ManufractorCategories
    .Where(o => o.Active == active)
    .Where(o => o.Folder == folder)
    .Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Folder })
    .Where(o => 
       !db.Manufractor_Categories
          .Select(t => t.Manufractor_id)
          .Contains(o.Id)
    .Distinct();
```

And a simplified version using query syntax:

```
var q = 
  from o in db.ManufractorCategories
  where o.Active == active && o.Folder == folder &&
        db.Manufractor_Categories
          .Select(t => t.Manufractor_id)
          .Contains(o.Id)
  select new { i.Id, i.Folder };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Except` statement is going to get a list of objects with the `Category_id` property.  However, you're query has a result that contains objects with the `Id` and `Folder` properties.  The query will most likely be unable to see where these objects are equal, and so, the `Except` clause won't take effect.